# VBA automated replacing of "." to ","

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that insterts the value of TextBoxes into Cells of an Excel sheet. In case someone is typing e.g. "4.4" instead of "4,4", I want to automatically replace the dot with a comma. I am using the following code, but somehow nothing happens and the cell value still contains dots instead of commas.

```
Private Sub CmdFinish1_Click()
Worksheets("1").Range("C10").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Value & "mm"

Range("C10").Select
Range("C10").Activate
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

UserForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a problem of locale?

Comment: @VincentG I´m sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Not mind, I was thinking it might be a problem with decimal separator set in the Excel's properties, but you are using text here, so it's not the issue.

Comment: However, in one case you specify the worksheet, and in the next lines you don't, so it uses the current active worksheet,which can be or not `Worksheets("1")`

Comment: @VincentG ohhh, did not think of that. I´ll try that one.

Comment: `Worksheets("1").Range("C10").Value = Replace(UserForm.TextBox1.Value,".",",") & "mm"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why your code doesn't work but let's use pure VBA to make the replacement:

```
Private Sub CmdFinish1_Click()
    Worksheets("1").Range("C10").Value = UserForm.TextBox1.Value & "mm"
    Range("C10").Value = Replace(Range("C10").Value, ".", ",")
    UserForm.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this it is a locale thing as @VincentG suggested.

You could give the cell a custom number format of `#,##0.00 "mm"` - I'm not sure the correct format for your locality, but I chose one from those available and added `"mm"` on the end.

Your code can then be changed to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("1").Range("C10").Value = Val(UserForm.TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

The [VAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) turns the text input into a numeric value.  Will throw an error if you enter actual text though - so won't accept `A` for example.